# Find the formula for the linear part of a curve

Tags: limits, functions, logarithms

The function $f(x) = -log_2(1- (1-2^{-x})^m)$ seems to behave linearly as $x$ goes to infinity ($m$ is a natural integer)

[image]

Here are different values of $m$: red(up) is 30, blue is 80 and green(down) is 160

I try to find the equation $f(x) = ax +b$ for the linear part of the curve

For $a$ I think that I need to solve $a =  \lim_{x\to\infty} ( - log_2(1- (1-2^{-x-\Delta})^m) + log_2(1- (1-2^{-x})^m) )/\Delta $

From the looks of the curve i think $a= 1$, but I don't know how to proove it...

For $b$ (supposing $a = 1$) I start to solve $x + b = \lim_{x\to\infty} log_2(1- (1-2^{-x})^m) $

But I am unable to express $b$ as a function of $m$...

Can someone help me ? I am not good enough with the interactions between limits and logarithms, and I am stuck after a few steps of the resolutions...  Thanks in advance !

Comment: Big hint: For small values of $y$, $$ (1+y)^{\alpha} \approx 1+\alpha y $$
And in this case, $y$ definitely is small.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found why a = 1 and b = -log2(m). This was the perfect hint to give :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial theorem,

$$1-(1-2^{-x})^m=m2^{-x}-\frac{m(m-1)}22^{-2x}+\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)}62^{-3x}-\cdots\approx m2^{-x}.$$

Then taking the base-$2$ cologarithm,

$$x-\log_2m.$$